# Covariant derivative of a constant vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to figure out that if $X$ is locally constant, i.e. in some coordinate system, the coefficient function is a constant function, then whether the covariant derivative of $X$ is 0. In $\mathbb R^n$ I guess this is true. But what about the general case, how can I derive this from the properties of covariant derivative?

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly not true - in fact, for *any* non-vanishing vector field $X$ there is a coordinate system $x^i$ in which $X = \partial/\partial x^1$. Remember the coordinate formula for the covariant derivative is $$\nabla_i X^j = \partial_i X^j + \Gamma_{ik}^j X^k,$$ so the equivalence of $X$ being parallel (zero covariant derivative) and having constant components holds only when the Christoffel symbols vanish. This is true only in flat spaces, and even then only in particular coordinates.

Comment: I believe that this is written in abstract index notation, right? $X^j$ is not the $j$-th coordinate of  $X$, but rather stands for the field $X$ with an abstract index $j$, right? Otherwise I don't see how that could be true.

Comment: @AlexM. You can interpret it as a genuine coordinate formula so long as you read $\nabla_i X^j$ as $(\nabla_i X)^j$.